# Python Divide a string

Tags: python, string, split, divide

I have a string like this:

```
 <td casd2" aasdeft" class="satyle3">
    <b><a asddidasd?ct=Peasds&amp;fasdaao=Monsdar
    &amp;pID=19635"...
```

I need the 19635.

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Is your string from an HTML document? It looks *almost* like HTML.

Comment: Yes, I think so: if it is html, then you could (actually, I would even say you should) use parsers in addition to regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use regular expressions to make a more neat solution:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '<td casd2" aasdeft" class="satyle3"><b><a asddidasd?ct=Peasds&amp;fasdaao=Monsdar&amp;pID=19635"...'
>>> match = re.search(".*pID=(\d+).*",s)
>>> if match:
...   match.group(1)
... 
'19635'
```

Nice and simple isn't it?

Comment: I guess `re.search` would be nicer and simpler.

Comment: in this case doesn't make much difference, but you're right. Edited!

Comment: match.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: yeah, that's a common error, you should ask first `if match:` because re.search returns `None` if the pattern wasn't found. Edited!

Comment: Why are you stuffing the regex with `.*` on each side? You can just use `match = re.search("pID=(\d+)",s)`.

Answer (score 3):

With what little information given, this is how I'd approach it:

```
import re

someString = ... # your original string

m = re.search(r"pID=(\d+)", someString)
pid = m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are parsing HTML/XML, it's best to use the right tool. re can get the job done quick and dirty; but will come back to bite you when you extend later (software that is not dead always evolves) or  you need to handle other forms of representation of the same data.

[Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) in python provides good parsing routines -- it's worth going thru' the learning curve.